# Datastage decimal separator, how can modify?

Tags: datastage

I am using datastage in order to generate a csv file with teradata source, when i modifu the job properties searching comma as a decimal separator in local categories it dosnt change, what is the correct way to do this change ?

Answer (score 0):

My issues: datasource teradata, with a job action need to transfor and get out a csv file, but had more than 8 decimal files, my datastage configuration have point as a decimal separator and i need comma. In teradata more than 8 oreplaces give u back row over size error.

Solution: Get the source and cast to varchar, and with datastage trasnform used change function converting the replacing comma in place to point, and get out fields with varchar data type with correct decimal separator.